# Getting text From a Label in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been assigned to make a calculator in tkinter fro my CS class. I want to use variables to save the numbers inputed but I think getting those from the label would be best. I was trying this:

```
num1 = label1.cget("text")
num2 = label1.cget("text")
```

So obviously this didn't work because I'm asking the question.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: why didn't it work? Do you get an error? Are you getting the wrong value? Does your program crash?

Comment: I was being presented with num2 being referenced before assignment although I crossed the variables over into all needed classes and I eventually globalized both of them.

Comment: Scratch that, I changed where the variables were presented and I was no longer getting that error but instead I received: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Those errors are all telling you useful information. Assume that python errors are always telling the truth. For example, an empty string is indeed an invalid integer, so you have to look through your code to figure out why you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer.

Comment: My teacher thinks your a genius, haha! Thanks for the help it is working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = label1["text"]
```

But remember it will give you the text as a string, you you will need to convert it to a number.

Comment: I converted to an Integer and a float and neither worked as I was presented with this:   num = float(label1.cget("text"))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: